# SQL: Counting the answers from a multiple-choice result

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a number of responses for a multiple-choice questionnaire. My goal is to count the number of respondents who answered 'A', 'B' etc and further process that data.

(The raw data is in JSON but this could be table data too. The JSON format isn't really a factor but if there's a better way of fetching the results form JSON then I'm open to ideas).

I have two methods of counting the responses, but my approach only produces one set of totals per question.

**Method 1: Sum Case**

```sql
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = N'[
  {"q1": "B", "q2": "B"},
  {"q1": "C", "q2": "C"},
  {"q1": "D", "q2": "C"},
  {"q1": "A", "q2": "B"},
  {"q1": "A", "q2": "B"},
  {"q1": "C", "q2": "A"},
  {"q1": "C", "q2": "B"}
]';

SELECT 
    Count(*) as total,
    sum(case when q1 = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as A,
    sum(case when q1 = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as B,
    sum(case when q1 = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as C,
    sum(case when q1 = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) as D
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
  WITH (
    q1 NVARCHAR(50) '$.q1',
    q2 NVARCHAR(50) '$.q2'
  )
```

**Results:**

| total | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 |

**Method 2: Pivot**

```sql
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = N'[
  {"q1": "B", "q2": "B"},
  {"q1": "C", "q2": "C"},
  {"q1": "D", "q2": "C"},
  {"q1": "A", "q2": "B"},
  {"q1": "A", "q2": "B"},
  {"q1": "C", "q2": "A"},
  {"q1": "C", "q2": "B"}
]';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
  WITH (
    q1 NVARCHAR(50) '$.q1'
  ) t
PIVOT(
    COUNT(q1)
    FOR q1 IN 
    (
        [A],
        [B],
        [C],
        [D]
    )
) as pivot_table
```

**Results:**

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 |

**Desired outcome**

Is there a way in which I can count all the questions with a single statement?

| Question | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| q1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| q2 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 0 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `WITH` might get `q1,q2` instead of `q1,q1`

Because `q1` and `q2` are two-columns we can try to use `CROSS APPLY` value to make unpivot, then use the aggregate condition function.

```
SELECT 
    v.Question,
    sum(case when v.val = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as A,
    sum(case when v.val = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as B,
    sum(case when v.val = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as C,
    sum(case when v.val = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) as D
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
  WITH (
    q1 NVARCHAR(50) '$.q1',
    q2 NVARCHAR(50) '$.q2'
  ) 
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('q1',q1),('q2',q2)) v(Question,val)
GROUP BY v.Question
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=7a043c5d12e76cfae0d771cf5f450a9b)

Comment: You're right. Correct with the typo to `q1,q2`
This is great! Not worked much with `CROSS APPLY` so I've got some learning to do.